# Incorrect file path for nul.h filename of #line directive

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, directive

### Problem

On `msvs14`, using [`#line`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5w2czay.aspx) directive with `filename` ending with `nul.h`, for example:

```cpp
#line 1 "nul.h"
```

shows incorrect file path as mysterious `\\.\nul` instead of `__FILE__/../nul.h`

### Example

```cpp
#pragma message(__FILE__)
#line 1 "../../nul.h"
die();
```

produces:

> ```
> 1>  c:\users\benio\documents\visual studio 2015\node\utils\lists.h
> 1>\\.\nul(1): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
> ```

### Question

1. Why it happens?
2. What is the source of this mysterious `\\.\nul`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aaargh!  You have been bitten by a very nasty piece of backwards compatability that dates back to around DOS 1.0.

There are a few names (NUL, CON, and PRN are examples) which are [special](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS#Reserved_device_names) (NUL is a null device, CON is the console, and PRN is a printer).  The problem is that these magical names predate directories and ignore file extensions - so whenever the compiler tries to open '".\nul.h"`, Windows spots this, says "Ah ha!  You are probably running a program which relies on DOS backwards compatability, and you want to open the null device instead" - so the compiler gets an error.

`\\.\nul` is the canonical name of the nul device.

Tl;dr:  You will have to change the name of your include file.  Call it `"null.h"` instead.